# How to make Custom STS receive SAML token from client as client credential for authentication?

Tags: c#, wcf, saml, wif, ws-federation

I have a custom STS service that receives username/password as client credential and generate token if username/password is valid. I do the username/password check in our own user store.

However now I need to make my custom STS receive SAML 2.0 token (issued from other identity provider) and validate the token, validate claim and generate token for the relying party (WCF service) which only trusts the token from custom STS.

Is there any way we can do it? Any sample out there?

I tried "IssuedToken" as client credential type but not sure how do I go about it. Any help is much appreciated.

I tried [this](https://leastprivilege.com/2010/10/28/wif-adfs-2-and-wcfpart-6-chaining-multiple-token-services/), but it seems outdated.

Comment: dotnet core or classic dotnet?

Comment: Go back to the website you linked and have a look at their opensource IdentityServer framework. Investigate whether you can use that, as it looks like you are trying to build what they already did. These guys are serious about security.